# Is the Splatoon demo an earlier build than the final game?

Tags: version-differences, splatoon

Does it have any differences, at all, that are not strictly demo stuff, like having "demo" on the title screen? Or was it made after the game was finalized, and it was just for testing the server, not the game itself?

Comment: I believe the demo periods were simply stress tests.

Comment: The demo during the stress tests was basically the bare minimum that was needed to get people into the Turf Wars multiplayer mode. There's a lot to the game that wasn't included in the demo, such as the single player campaign, most of the weapons, most of the maps, the plaza, equipment, ranked matches, etc.